# Integer programming proof: If an LP is unbounded then the IP is unbounded

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, linear-programming, integer-programming

Given an integer program

Max c$^T$x 
subject to Ax $\le$ b 
$\quad\quad\quad\quad$ x$\in$Z$^+$

Show that if A and b are rational and there exists at least one feasible solution to the integer program and the linear programming relaxation is unbounded, then the integer program is also unbounded.

I'm honestly not sure where to start..I think I need to show that the linear program has some direction I can go in forever, and I can always get to an integer point somewhere along that direction since A and b are rational. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You might want to check https://www.jstor.org/stable/170919, 
Recognizing Unbounded Integer Programs
R. H. Byrd, A. J. Goldman and Miriam Heller
Operations Research
Vol. 35, No. 1 (Jan. - Feb., 1987), pp. 140-142

Comment: The key idea is that the simplex method generates a rational direction in which the program is unbounded. Adding this direction to integer feasible points proves the unboundedness of IP